# Tomcat window will close automatically after start up

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I tried to start tomcat but the tomcat window will close automatically,
Even tried to run catalina.bat run command to see the error found a list of exceptions...does any body have idea what is going on?

My JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are set perfectly , the servers used to run perfectly before I started to get this issues after i tried to build and run custom tag in my jsp page.

```
07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.436 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ForTesting]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ForTesting]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> */ in filter mapping
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.validateFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2970)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addFilterMap(StandardContext.java:2919)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1271)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1176)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.577 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.718 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more

07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.827 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.843 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.858 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.874 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:533)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.952 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
07-Dec-2016 11:41:28.952 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:533)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: *Invalid <url-pattern> */ in filter mapping*

Comment: Please read the error stack. It says "....Invalid <url-pattern> */ ...". If you have given <url-pattern> as */ change it to /.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i got no idea what does that mean. do u mean to chage soem url-patern in my web.xml file in ROOT FOLDER?

Comment: Have you deployed any web application in tomcat webapps folder??

Comment: @SachinSarawgi Yes i did, though i had no trouble loading previous application  the issue started after i used custom tags in one of my application.

Comment: Okay. Please check your web.xml file of the web-app. Check the <url-pattern> tag whether it has the value "*/". Then we will go to next step.

Comment: @charle819 did you check??

Comment: @SachinSarawgi yes i do have that in <url-pattern> in one of my applications , what do you suggest i should do?

Comment: I already told check if it has value "*/". Or please tell what value its written their.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi i changed the<url-pattern> form "*/" to "/" as u suggested in the previous comment still no luck

Comment: In your tomcat go to tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost folder and delete every content from their.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi i did delete everything from the folder u mentioned but still the same execeptions

Comment: If you are getting the same exception means the web.xml content is still same. Stop tomcat, delete war file and app folder from tomcat/webapps folder, delete content from tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost folder, if you are coding in an IDE make the edit, export the war file to the tomcat/webapps folder. Start tomcat server. Please follow the steps as mentioned.

Comment: Also you can check if you have properly modified the web.xml file or not by going to "tomcat/webapps/yourwebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml". And keep in mind for this setting to take affect you must not have old cache in "tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/yourwebapp"

Comment: @SachinSarawgi i deleted everything as u said , but empty folders do get created of my application when i start tomcat again, i think i'll just delete tomcat and reinstall it... thanks for the help though hope the issue doesn't stay after i reinstall

Comment: I will be their, you can ping if you still get the same error. I will try to resolve this error.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi sweet mother, just solved the issue i had not changed the web.xml of my application which was present in wtpwebapps folder. thanks a lot for the help sir

Comment: @charle819 just posted the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error stack says  "....Invalid  */ ...".

Please follow below steps to get it resolved:

> Stop tomcat server
>
> Go to tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost. Delete every content from their.
>
> Go to tomcat/webapps/yourwebapp/WEB-INF folder and edit web.xml file  from "*/" to "/".
>
> Go to tomcat/wtpwebapps/ folder. Edit web.xml file  from "*/" to "/"
>
> Now restart tomcat server the error will not be their.

Comment: also u need to delete or change the web.xml of your application  which is present in wtpwebapps folder , i had forget that one.